# How to ignore/overwrite existing css class

Tags: css, class, hidden

I use a tool that changes the original CSS code on a website.

I want to show a hidden text and have to overwrite the original class but have no idea how in this case. It's like a adblock protection.

The CSS class is:

```
.text-invisible{
    filter:url(#hidden-text)
}
```

I would be very happy about your help

Comment: You need to make use of CSS specificity. However, you'd need to show us your existing code for us to come up with a more specific selector. In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

CSS classes are applied from the top - down and their dominance is in that order.

You can also use the `!important` class, but doing so is often bad practice. If you do, however, use `!important`, make sure to add a note to why it was used for it can make code confusing and hard for someone else to edit your code without understanding why `!important` was used.

Example of the use of `!important`: `.text-invisible{ filter:url(#hidden-text) !important }`

This should work, but be careful if you're going to use it / try not to use it often.

Comment: .text-invisible{ filter:url(#hidden-text) }  is the original class and I want to "remove/overwrite" this hidden-text function.

Comment: Use the `.text-invisible` class and write it above the code you want to overwrite, adding in code to make it visible. or use `!important` on a class that makes it visible anywhere in the CSS file.